# Open popupdatefiled calendar programmatically

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

Is it possible to open the date selection calendar of the `PopUpDateField` programmatically?

I want to have something like a `DateRangeField` in Vaadin. It's made up of two `PopUpDateField`'s one for the first value ("from") and the other one for the "to" value. When the "from" value is changed I want that the calendar selection opens automatically for the "to" value, *without* the user needing to press the calendar icon of the "to" field.
[image]

I can't find this functionality anywhere in the [Vaadin DateField components](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-datefield.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there's no built-in support for that in the Vaadin `DateField`.

The cleanest solution would be to create your own Vaadin [extension](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/gwt/gwt-extension.html), which would provide server-side API to open the popup for a `DateField`.

The easiest but a bit hackish solution is to defined a unique id for your datefield

```
dateField.setId("my-datefield");
```

and use Vaadin JavaScript API to execute a JavaScript snippet that clicks a button in the DateField's client-side element:

```
JavaScript.eval("document.getElementById('my-datefield').childNodes[1].click()");
```